# c++ variable assignment, is this a normal way..?

Tags: c++, variables, styles, variable-assignment

This may be a silly question, but still I'm a bit curious...
Recently I was working on one of my former colleague projects, and I've noticed that he really loved to use something like this:

```
int foo(7);
```

instead of:

```
int foo = 7;
```

Is this a normal/good way to do in C++ language?
Is there some kind of benefits to it? (*Or is this just some silly programming style that he was into..?*)

This really reminds me a bit of a good way how class member variables can be assigned in the class constructor... something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass(int foo) : mFoo(foo)
   { }

private:
   int   mFoo;
};
```

instead of this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass(int foo)
   {
      mFoo = foo; 
   }

private:
   int   mFoo;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For basic types there's no difference. Use whichever is consistent with the existing code and looks more natural to you.

Otherwise,

```
A a(x);
```

performs **direct initialization**, and

```
A a = x;
```

performs **copy initialization**.

The second part is a member initializer list, there's a bunch of Q&As about it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Both are valid. For builtin types they do the same thing; for class types there is a subtle difference.

```
MyClass m(7);  // uses MyClass(int)
MyClass n = 3; // uses MyClass(int) to create a temporary object,
               // then uses MyClass(const MyClass&) to copy the
               // temporary object into n
```

The obvious implication is that if `MyClass` has no copy constructor, or it has one but it isn't accessible, the attempted construction fails. If the construction would succeed, the compiler is allowed to skip the copy constructor and use `MyClass(int)` directly.

Comment: If MyClass c-tor is explicit it will fails too.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above are correct. Just add that to it that C++11 supports another way, a generic one as they say to initialize variables.

```
int a = {2} ;
```

or

```
int a {2} ;
```

Comment: How is this different from the other way(s)?

Comment: `{}` is used to assign from a series of values, rather than calling a specific constructor.  Specficially: `vector<int> a = {1, 2}`, constructs a vector holding those as two elements, wheras `vector<int> a(1, 2)` constructs a vector with one element.

Comment: The `{}` uniform initialization syntax can be used without the `=`. (with `=` it does copy initialization.) @MooingDuck Also it doesn't have to use an initializer_list constructor, it just happens to prefer initializer_list constructors if there's one that matches. `struct S { S(char const *c, int i) {} }; S s{"hey", 2};`

Comment: @bames53: Forgot it doesn't need the `=`.  You're right that it _can_ use other constructors, but it _shouldn't_ be used for other constructors, other than those that act like initializer_list constructors.  EG, default constructors and conversion constructors.

Comment: @MooingDuck I disagree that it shouldn't be used except for list-like constructors. It's good for avoiding the most vexing parse. Also IMO it would be reasonable in new code to use uniform initialization syntax everywhere except in the rare instances that the `()` syntax must be used.

Comment: @bames53: WRT most-vexing-parse: usually for those I use the `=` syntax to avoid the problem.  As for the rare: I partially agree with that.  Most initialization _is_ initialization-list-like, or a copy.

Answer (score 2):

It's a C++ style of initializing variables - C++ added it for fundamental types so the same form could be used for fundamental and user-defined types.  this can be very important for template code that's intended to be instantiated for either kind of type.

Whether you like to use it for normal initialization of fundamental types is a style preference.

Note that C++11 also adds the [uniform initialization syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization) which allows the same style of initialization to be used for all types - even aggregates like POD structs and arrays (though user defined types may need to have a new type of constructor that takes an initialization list to allow the uniform syntax to be used with them).

Comment: But keep in mind that uniform initialization syntax is _not_ a complete replacement for the old `()` constructor calls.  Uniform initialization should be used to initialize from a series of one or more values, and `()` for any other constructor.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It seems to me that things are still in flux regarding what will be the recommended practice regarding whether uniform initialization should be used uniformly or not.

Comment: If you mean "should be used uniformly" as in _always_, then that's a clear no, as the `{}` syntax cannot call all constructors.  Otherwise, yeah, there seems to be more debate than I thought there was.

Answer (score 2):

Several other good answers point out the difference between constructing "in place" (`ClassType v(<constructor args>)`) and creating a temporary object and using the copy constructor to copy it (`ClassType v = <constructor arg>`). Two additional points need to be made, I think. First, the second form obviously has only a single argument, so if your constructor takes more than one argument, you should prefer the first form (yes, there are ways around that, but I think the direct construction is more concise and readable - but, as has been pointed out, that's a personal preferance).

Secondly, the form you use matters if your copy constructor does something significantly different than your standard constructor. This won't be the case most of the time, and some will argue that it's a bad idea to do so, but the language does allow for this to be the case (all surprises you end up dealing with because of it, though, are your own fault).

Answer (score 2):

Yours is not a silly question at all as things are not as simple as they may seem. Suppose you have:

```
class A {
  public:
    A() {}
};
```

and

```
class B {
  public:
    class B(A const &) {}
};
```

Writing

```
B b = B(A());
```

Requires that B's copy constructor be accessible. Writing

```
B b = A();
```

Requires also that B's converting constructor B(A const &) be not declared explicit. On the other hand if you write

```
A a;
B b(a);
```

all is well, but if you write

```
B b(A());
```

This is interpreted by the compiler as the declaration of a function b that takes a nameless argument which is a parameterless function returning A, resulting in mysterious bugs. This is known as [C++'s most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using the parenthetical style...though I always use a space to distinguish from function or method calls, on which I don't use a space:

```
int foo (7); // initialization
myVector.push_back(7); // method call
```

One of my reasons for preferring using this across the board for initialization is because it helps remind people that it is *not* an assignment.  Hence overloads to the assignment operator will not apply:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar {
private:
    int value;
public:
    Bar (int value) : value (value) {
        std::cout << "code path A" << "\n";
    }
    Bar& operator=(int right) {
        value = right;
        std::cout << "code path B" << "\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Bar b = 7;
    b = 7;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
code path A
code path B
```

It feels like the presence of the equals sign obscures the difference.  Even if it's "common knowledge" I like to make initialization look notably different than assignment, since we are able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the syntax for initialization of something :-

```
SomeClass data(12, 134);
```

That looks reasonable, but

```
int data(123);
```

Looks strange but they are the same syntax.

Comment: You might think it looks strange, but for me it does not look strange at all :P

Comment: Ok, looks strange if you are not used to it. I increasingly write my code like this for consistency now.

Comment: Matter of taste I guess.  I initialize ints, double's etc. using the equal sign.  Even a kid can understand what `int a = 5` means.

Comment: To tell the truth, my practice shows that sometimes style like `int foo(7);` can be really confusing...! Imagine if you have someting like this `typedef int Foos;` and somewhere deep in some guys code you wind something like this `Foos someFoo(7);` .. Normally I would think that "Foos" is some kind of class, and that I'm assigning value "7" through the "Foos" constructor...